# Connectedness of a union of convex sets

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, convex-geometry

Let $p_1,...,p_k$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $S_1,...,S_m$ be subsets of $\{p_1,...,p_k\}$, and let $V_i$ be the convex hull of $S_i$. Is it true that \begin{equation}
V:=\bigcup_{i=1}^m V_i
\end{equation} is path-connected if and only if any two $p_i,p_j\in V$ can be joined in $V$ by a concatenation of line segments whose endpoints belong to $\{p_1,...,p_k\}$?

In other words, we can define a graph $G$ whose vertices are the points $p_i$ appearing in at least one $S_j$, and put an edge between $p_{i_1},p_{i_2}$ if and only if $\{p_{i_1},p_{i_2}\}\subseteq S_j$ for some $j$. Then my question is, is $V$ path-connected if and only if $G$ is a connected graph?

I feel like it should be easy to argue that yes but I have a hard time deducing something combinatoric from something topological.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implication: "$\Leftarrow$" is obviously true.

But the other implication is false. Consider 4 points forming a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$p_1=(0,0),\ p_2=(0,1),\ p_3=(1,0),\ p_4=(1,1)$$

and let $S_1=\{p_1,p_4\}$ and $S_2=\{p_2,p_3\}$. Then $V$ is a union of two diagonals which is path connected. Note that $V_1\cap V_2=\{(1/2,1/2)\}$ which is not a vertex. And thus clearly $p_1$ and $p_2$ cannot be joined by concatenating line segments ending at any $(p_i,p_j)$. In this case such lines coincide with $V_1,V_2$.

Comment: Thank you, I see that I am lacking assumptions because this can not happen in my specific problem but of course your answer is prefectly correct

Comment: @MarcoFlores I think that the assumptions you are looking for is that $V$ is a simplicial complex. And so each $S_i$ is a simplex and $S_i\cap S_j$ is a simplex as well. This the reason why my example works: because $V_1\cap V_2$ is not a vertex. If $V$ is a simplicial complex then I think your conjecture is true.